# freezing of code!!. at line while np.equal(users,result.placeID).any():

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
import numpy as np
users = result['placeID'].unique()
print(len(users))
count=0
for X in users:
    while np.equal(X,result.placeID).any():
        count+=result.ave_rating
print(count)
```

basic python code using `pandas` and `numpy`, showing error as `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` at line 6 in the above code: `while np.equal(users,result.placeID)`. [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOXNi.png)

after solving this issue by using `.any()` the code now just freeze.

Comment: indent your code properly

Comment: done!, please have a look